# Comparar valores de una celda de distintas filas para un id especifico con pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Como puedo cambiar el valor de una columna dependiendo cierta validación entre algunas celdas.

En este ejemplo para cada id tengo q validar si el kilometraje en la fila es mayor o igual que el kilometraje del mismo id en la próxima fila q aparezca y si es menor cambiar el valor de error_km de la fila q este mal a ERROR.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que con withColumn puedo sobre escribir o crear una columna q no existe y que usando when puedo poner condiciones. Por ejemplo:
Este seria el código que uso para validar la columna estado e id_cliente y sobre escribir con ERROR la columna error_code donde corresponda:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

file_path = 'Direccion del archivo'

error = 'Esto es un error'

df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
df = df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df = df.select('estado', 'id_cliente')
df = df.withColumn("error_code", lit(''))

df = df.withColumn('error_code',
                            F.when((F.col('estado') == 'O') &
                                    (F.col('id_cliente') != '') |
                                    (F.col('estado') == 'D') &
                                    (F.col('id_cliente') != '') |
                                    (F.col('estado') == 'A') &
                                    (F.col('id_cliente') == ''),
                                     F.concat(F.col("error_code"), F.lit(":[{}]".format(error)))
                                   )
                             .otherwise(F.col('error_code')))
```